# Variables get corrupted

Tags: objective-c, crash, exc-bad-access

I’m developing an iPhone App using Objective-C, based on Apple’s UIKit.

I’ve created some class instance in UIViewController and found my class instance pointer get corrupted randomly. Due to class instance pointer corrupted, I always get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash like this:
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa095633c
    Crashed Thread:  0

It shows that when my code is trying to access the class instance, it’s already turned into a ridiculous address:0xa095633c, which is beyond memory space and even binary image space.

Does any have any suggestion what kind of incorrect coding could possibly lead to class instance get corrupted?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things that can cause that. Just to name a few:

- Accessing an already deleted object
- Improper multithreading
- Bugs in pointer arithmetic
- Stack corruption
- Going out of array's bounds

Learn to use debugger and debug logging to track down where and when the invalid pointer has appeared.

Try to create a small test program which reproduces the problem so you can post code example.

Comment: For about half of those, you'd probably have to know what you were doing wrong to correctly reproduce it in a test case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue I’m encountering is quite random. I can’t even reproduce it with thousands times of retry.

Comment: Besides, I’ve tried NSZombie but no lucky. Didn’t find any of deallocated object get accessed. I think it’s tend to be an improper multithreading caused issue. Anything I should especially care in multithreading memory management?

Comment: @Chuck: While that is true, one can often reduce the existing code until a simple test program remains. But that requires some basic skills and insight into the problem, indeed. Such test programs are often more useful to report or demonstrate bugs in a library.

Comment: @user268743 indeed, random behavior is common for multithreading issues. Make sure you're using synchronization primitives to guard access to all data and objects that can ever be accessed by several threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually indicates a memory management error. Read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and make sure you conform to all the rules about alloc/retain/release/etc.

Comment: I didn’t even alloc anything to that class instance. The class instance should be nil when I was accessing it. (I simply NSLog it’s pointer and hope to see the null result.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to retain the object when assigning to a variable?

A quick example:

```
variable = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] retain];
```

Another solution could be to declare an instance variable as property with the attribute "retain":

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *variable;
```

Comment: I didn’t even alloc anything to that class instance. The class instance should be nil when I was accessing it. (I simply NSLog it’s pointer and hope to see the null result.)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this kind of error is the object getting deallocated prematurely and some other memory is getting written in its place. Try turning on Zombies in Instruments and it will tell you if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I’ve tried NSZombie but no lucky. Didn’t find any of deallocated object get accessed.